# С какого медиа элемента произошло событие?

Tags: javascript, html5

Как узнать с какого медиа элемента произошло событие (play, pause и т.д.)?
Например, если есть страница с несколькими элементами:

```
<body>
    <video controls name="media" src="1.mp4"></video>
    <video controls name="media" src="2.mp4"></video>
    <video controls name="media" src="3.mp4"></video>
</body>
```

Comment: Как вариант: ты можешь раздать каждому тегу video свой id и слушать у этих id событие onclick:)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев, не обязательно это делать, можно и по индексу элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var vds = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

for (var i = 0; i < vds.length; i++) {
  vds[i].addEventListener('play', catchEvent);
}

function catchEvent(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<video id="v1" controls name="media" src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" width="320" height="240"></video>
<video id="v2" controls name="media" src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" width="320" height="240"></video>
<video id="v3" controls name="media" src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" width="320" height="240"></video>
```